# How to embed answer prompts in bash script

Tags: bash, command-prompt

I am automating a binary installation from a shell script. The binary asks 4 questions like:

```
Do you want to configure proxy settings (yes/no)? yes

Examples:
http://squid.mycompany.com:3128
https://username:password@squid.mycompany.com:443

proxy url: http://proxy.abc.company.net:8080
These are your proxy settings:
protocol: "http"
host: "proxy.abc.company.net"
port: "8080"
Are these correct? (yes/no) yes
We recommend using NTPD to keep the time in sync.
Do you want to install and configure this now (yes/no)? no
```

What I am trying is :

```
echo -e "yes\n'"'$PROXY_URL'"'\nyes\nno\n" | bash installer-new-kvm-debian.sh
```

But I am getting error that:

```
No TTY available. Skipping all prompts...
No TTY available. Skipping all prompts...
```

Any idea what's wrong I'm doing or is there any other way to achieve the same ?

Comment: Look at the tool's documentation for how to safely and robustly automate installation. Pressing keys on a keyboard is a human thing, and simulating that does not make for a good integration point.

Comment: You can use use Expect, "a program to automate interactions with programs that expose a text terminal interface"

Comment: The binary seems to support automatic installations. since it is checking `tty`. Try to find parameters used for this.